Kantian Subjectivism Contradiction?
Kant rendered the judgments of reason as subjective, neither narrating nor accurately reflecting the reality of things.

"We only sense from external objects, thus perception does not express reality but rather our emotional response to reality."


Immanuel Kant(Sorry,i don't really know if this is the right translation).

Kant faltered in proving the validity of senses as it incapacitates the mind from its full functions, contradicting his doctrine rooted in reason in epistemology.
The contradiction arises when one accepts that knowledge begins with experience, then claims that the mind, being silent, does not reveal the truth of anything. How can one prove that experience is indeed real? Through intuition and conscience? If one were to bring forth rational evidence of the truth of experience, they would fall into the trap of conceiving the thing in itself or the role and sequence accordingly, as judgments for Kant only exist in the realm of proof, both leading to the impossibility claim Kant makes.
So how would one prove that experience is indeed real without leading themselves into the trap of conceiving the thing in itself or the role and sequence. And did kant have any solution for this contradiction(if we can call it a contradiction).

Where is that quote from? It doesn't look like something Kant would say.

To answer the question:

So how would one prove that experience is indeed real without leading
themselves into the trap of conceiving the thing in itself or the role
and sequence?

Kant’s turn in thinking is radical: Humans do not experience, instead they construct experience. Kant is one of the founders of constructivism.
We process the input of sense data by two forms of intuition, time and space, and subsequently by 12 categories. The output is our experience. These 2+12 mental tools are important ingredients to shape the form of the output. For more details see Kant: Critique of Pure Reason .
